# Unsolvable computational problems, other than The Halting Problem

Tags: algorithms

Whenever I read about **unsolvable computational problems**, the example cited is Turing's Halting Problem.  Are there any other instances of unsolvable computational problems?

Comment: There is no algorithm to determine whether a diophantine equation has a solution.

Comment: the word problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups

Comment: Post's correspondence problem, mortality problem with matrices are other examples. And not to forget , Conways game of life : There is no algorithm to determine whether some cell will live forever.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327609/are-there-any-turing-undecidable-problems-whose-undecidability-is-independent-of/1327620#1327620) for some discussion of unsolvable problems which are *extremely* different from the halting problem by way of being neither harder nor either in [a precise sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) (at a glance the examples given above are each equivalent to the halting problem in this sense).

Comment: [Busy Beaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) is another interesting example.

Comment: Crossposted at [CSSE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/144480/unsolvable-computational-problems-other-than-the-halting-problem).